Register page doesn't connect to Firebase
I am trying to do the register page to my app but I get a lot of errors at the setState() action to name , email and password register. Here is the code , what I should change for my user to be able to register , either as a client , either as a business account. Should I create another file ? auth.dart? I also get error at final Authentication authentication = authentication and at selectedValue and selectedString
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'LoginPage.dart';
import 'transport_category.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}
  String email = '';
  String password = '';
  String error = '';
  String _selectedRole = 'Select a User Role';
  String get selectedRole => _selectedRole;

  int selectedValue;
  String selectedString;
  
  var elements1 = [
    'Customer',
    'Business',
  ];
  String dropdownvalue = 'Customer';
  bool loading = false;
  final Authentication authentication = Authentication();
  int selectedIndex1 = 0;

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0, left: 30, right: 30),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              Logo(),
              SignUpButton(),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              LoginButton(),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}

class UserProfile extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  UserProfileState createState() => UserProfileState();
}

class UserProfileState extends State<UserProfile> {
  // Map<String, dynamic> _profile;
  bool _loading = false;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Subscriptions are created here
    //  authService.profile.listen((state) => setState(() => _profile = state));

    //authService.loading.listen((state) => setState(() => _loading = state));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: <Widget>[
      //  Container(padding: EdgeInsets.all(20), child: Text(_profile.toString())),
      Text(_loading.toString())
    ]);
  }
}

class SignUpButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Form(
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
              padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 10.0),
              child: TextFormField(
                validator: (val) => val.isEmpty ? 'enter name' : null,
                          onChanged: (val) {
                            setState(() => name = val);
                          },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "First and Last Name",
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18),
                      borderSide: BorderSide.none),
                  fillColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
                  filled: true,
                  // prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.person)),
                ),
              )),
          Padding(
              padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 10.0),
              child: TextFormField(
                          validator: (val) => val.length < 8
                              ? 'enter password > 8 digits'
                              : null,
                          onChanged: (val) {
                            setState(() => password = val);
                          },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "Email",
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18),
                        borderSide: BorderSide.none),
                    fillColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
                    filled: true,
                    prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.person)),
              )),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 10.0),
            child: TextFormField(
                          validator: (val) => val.length < 8
                              ? 'enter password > 8 digits'
                              : null,
                          onChanged: (val) {
                            setState(() => password = val);
                          },
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: "Password",
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18),
                    borderSide: BorderSide.none),
                fillColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
                filled: true,
                prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.password),
              ),
              obscureText: true,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Container(
              height: 62,
              width: 350,
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
              child: DropdownButton(
                isExpanded: true,
                value: dropdownvalue,
                icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
                items: elements1.map((String items) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem(value: items, child: Text(items));
                }).toList(),
                onChanged: (String? value) {
                   setState(() {
                              dropdownvalue = newValue;
                            });
                },
              )),
          SizedBox(
            height: 30,
          ),
          Container(
            height: 62,
            width: 350,
            child: ElevatedButton(
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
                  )),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LocationPage()));
              },
              child: Text(
                'Sign Up',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start, children: <Widget>[
            Icon(
              Icons.email,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 40,
            ),
          ])
        ])),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class LoginButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 330.0, // Button width
            height: 62.0,
            child: ElevatedButton(
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
                ),
              ),
              child: Text(
                '        I already have account',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage()),
                );

                // )
                //        // Navigate to second route when tapped.
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Logo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Text("INFLUFIT",
              style: GoogleFonts.bebasNeue(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 50,
                color: Colors.black,
              )),
        ]);
  }
}


What's the error message?

it's no error message, I can't run the code , it shows red lines

https://imgur.com/a/oBp4spd

Give selectedValue and selectedString an initial value or make them nullable like this:
int? selectedValue;
String? selectedString;
and make sure to give them a value later.
read about null safety.
about final Authentication authentication = Authentication(); can you show me the error message

https://imgur.com/a/kYGtceM look

https://imgur.com/a/5XVpoak

Place the mouse cursor on the word to see the error
